# Custom Post Type Permalink / Rewrite not working immediately

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, rewrite-rules

Hitting a brick wall with the following:

I have:

- 1 custom post type called `cpt_community`
- 1 custom taxonomy called `tax_community`

If I set `'rewrite' => true` in my CPT registration, then permalinks to an entry for this CPT are of the form of `http://<domain>/cpt_community/test_item/`, and I get a 404 when browsing to it.

If I set  `'rewrite' => false`, then permalinks are `http://<domain>/?cpt_community=test_item/`, and this works fine.

So, I'm obviously doing something wrong/stupid - the question is, what?

[Update]

- After every change I'm flushing rules by going to Settings > Permalinks (and saving)
- After leaving everything alone for an hour, things have started working correctly - so why the delay?

---

**Code**

CPT Registration

```
function community_post_type() {
  $labels = array('name'  => 'Community');

   $args = array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_in_menu' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => false,
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'has_archive' => true,
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'menu_position' => null,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes')
   ); 

  register_post_type('cpt_community', $args);
}  
add_action( 'init', 'community_post_type' );
```

Custom Taxonomy Registration

```
function community_tax_type() {
  register_taxonomy(
    'tax_community',
    'cpt_community',
     array( 'hierarchical' => false,
       'label' => 'Community Content Type',
       'show_ui' => true,'query_var' => true,
       'rewrite' => true,
       'singular_label' => 'Community Content Type',
       'capabilities' => array('assign_terms' => 'edit_community_tags')
       )
   );
   # allow roles to add community taxonomy tags to a community CPT
   $roles = array("subscriber","contributor","author","editor","administrator");

   foreach ($roles as $role_name) {
     $role = get_role($role_name);
     $role->add_cap("edit_community_tags");
   }   
}
add_action( 'init', 'community_tax_type' );
```

Comment: you've flushed rewrites first by visiting permalinks page and saving?

Comment: @milo - yup. Interestingly, after walking away for an hour and then coming back, the 'pretty permalinks' are now working - I'll update the question and frame it as a 'why the delay'

Comment: Do you use a caching plugin? Does it work faster with all other plugins disabled? (Just getting the usual suspects out of the way)

Comment: @jan - no caching plugin. The problem is that I can't reproduce this behaviour - it's happened a couple of times now and goes away after but with no specific action (that I can tell) to actually fix it.

Answer (score 8):

Use the function flush_rewrite_rules() for set the rewrite rules new, but not with your code on init-hook, only on activation plugin or theme! See more in my post: http://wpengineer.com/2044/custom-post-type-and-permalink/

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

Flush rules *only* on activation (and deactivation). Don't do it on any other hook.

```
register_activation_hook()
```

Comment: You could also go to "settings => permalinks" and just click save without necessarily changing anything. The permalinks get regenerated then too.

Answer (score 4):

Just go to Settings>Permalinks to flash the rules. No code is needed.
You don't need to update the structure, just opening that admin page does the job

Comment: but you then have to visit that page every time an error occurs. By using the flush_rewrite_rules(); function means they get flushed with no real need for interaction.